# ionic app appearance changed at device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I created an ionic app 
and when I tried to test it at ionic view app
the appearance changed and the background image are not appear
what is the problem
and do you have another way to test the app on android rather than using ionic view app ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer this 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

Connect you android phone to your development machine. Enable USB debugging on the device.

Then run "ionic run android" on your command line.